# Register Shell Overlays in the user hive

Tags: windows, registry, explorer, shell-extensions

An overlay shell extension normally is registered in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
```

Is it also possbile to do that somewhere in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` ?

I'd like to install such an extension in an account without administrative privilieges.

Comment: According to this, they are system wide only. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/02e4fbf7-5541-4f86-bc6c-f95a1d8e73cb/how-to-get-overlay-icons-only-on-the-current-user-hoe-to-register-shelliconoverlayidentifiers-to?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Comment: @HansPassant: I don't see any reference to ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers on that page?  [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127455(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to be the relevant link, and it doesn't say either way.